# jquery validate: How to show and hide error summary?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have implemented an error summary according to this [example here:](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/numberOfInvalids)

while I get it to display, I don't have a clue how to hide it once there are no errors remaining.

I have [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/eDk2m/1/) to demonstrate it:

type in anything in either of the two fields, while the error messages go away, the summary still remains. There must be an event that I need to subscribe to, but I can't figure it out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var validator = validation_rules('#myform');
  validator.form();

  function validation_rules(form) {

    $.validator.addClassRules("fillone", {
      require_from_group: [1, ".fillone"]
    });

    var validator = $(form).validate({
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var field_error = $(form).find('#id_' + element.attr('name')).siblings('.field_error');
        if (field_error.length > 0) {
          error.appendTo(field_error);
        }

        $(field_error).show();
      },
      invalidHandler: function () {
        $("#validation_summary").text(validator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid");
      }

    });
    return validator;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the errorContainer option.  This will show/hide the specified elements when the form becomes valid/invalid

> errorContainer:{"#validation_summary"}

example is on http://jsfiddle.net/eDk2m/7

**edit after reading comment**

there is an event to hook into - a good example is in the [custom-methods-demo.html](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/demo/custom-methods-demo.html) page of the plugin demos.  It looks like this

```
var validator = $("form").bind("invalid-form.validate",  
function() { 
 var errorCount = validator.numberOfInvalids(); 
 // do other stuff here
}).validate({...});
```

Comment: This is a good solution. +1 from me. I was hoping there would be a kind of function I could hook into in order to make the tab header also in red color and remove the red once the errors have vanished. Like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/Nf8xY/6/  Do you think there is a way to make the TAB B red when there are errors and remove the style when there are no errors? Literally an event to hook into?

Comment: there is an event. it is "invalid-form.validate".  I'll edit the answer as I can format some code

Comment: Thank you that helped me in the right direction. There is still a problem with it. BUt I better start a new question.