# Failure Alert by a Submit Button on Bootstrap Form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm a little new to bootstrap, so be gentle with me lol ...

I have a long form, with maybe a dozen or so fields that need to be validated.
That all works just perfectly.

But on a phone, when the form fails to submit, and the submit button becomes "disabled" I wantan alert to appear above/below the Submit Button area warning the user they left mandatory fields black up above a=so they can scroll up and solve those issues...

This example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtglenn/VwPaR/)

is perfect to show what I want.

If you click on "Submit" without filling in any of the fields, you get alerts by the fields. Mine does that a-ok.

I want a "Warning Alert" bootstrap message box to appear by that submit button informing the use to fill in fields up above before submitting "again"

I'm at a loss on how to do this.
I thought I had a form sample showing "success" but can't find it anywhere all of sudden. My feeble code attempts all fail.

Searches keep pointing me to alerts placed right by the text fields, which I'm doing just fine already.

arghhh

```js
$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    fname: {
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 15,
      required: true
    },
    lname: {
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 15,
      required: true
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
  },
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorClass: 'help-block',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.length) {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="fname" class="control-label col-md-6">First Name:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name" />
      <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="fname1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="lname" class="control-label col-md-6">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last name" />
      <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="lname1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This example on GitHub may help --> [errorContainer](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html) and this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256004/jquery-validate-how-to-show-and-hide-error-summary

Comment: Where you want the `warning alert` to be placed?

Comment: Right above or below the submit button. I did find some "sample forms" that look like they do this, but can't duplicate what they do on my forms.

Comment: This is a sample I found: http://thrilleratplay.github.io/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip/  Could it be because I'm using the built in bootrapvalidator and not a specific jquery validator?